# How to solve Quota Warning in Webmail CPanel?

Tags: cpanel, quota, webmail

My C Panel Quota crosses limit. I cant access those emails.
How to Increase or decrease quota?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's so easy.

Go to Email Accounts from CPanel. Then Click on Change Quota. Then increase the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your account's disk space usage using Disk Space Usage option in cPanel. Please refer the URL below for the details:

---

### http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/DiskSpaceUsage

First, determine which files are using too much space. Log into cpanel and click “Disk usage.” You will see a list of directories, sorted by size, biggest to smallest. This will tell you where the problem is.

1. To free up some disk space login to email account via webmail, After login to webmail, delete allunwanted mails to increase the disk space.
2. Use an email client like MS Outlook to download all your emails to your local pc. 
   While downloading all emails to your local pc using MS Outlook, please make sure you leave the option 'Leave copy of mail on server' unchecked. This will make sure that the mails are not left on the server and will take care of the quota issu

In "Outlook" mail client it can be done via following step

On the Tools menu, click E-mail Accounts >> Click View or change existing e-mail accounts, and then click Next >> Select your ISP account, and then click Change >> Click More Settings >> Click the Advanced tab, and under Delivery, uncheck the Leave a copy of messages on the server check box.